# Quadratic residues with prime number

Tags: modular-arithmetic, set-theory, quadratic-residues

Let Define:

$$Q1=\{i^2\ mod\ p | 0\leq i<p\}$$
$$Q2=\{(-1)^i\cdot i^2\ mod\ p | 0\leq i<p\}$$
Let notice that for $p=47$ it can be shown that $|Q1|=24$ and $|Q2|=47$ but for other primary for example $p=5$ we get $|Q1|=|Q2|=3$. Explain the phenomenon and find a condition of prime number $p$ which gives us  $|Q2|=p$.

Attempt: I tried to look of a small prime numbers like 7 and 11 that the phenomenon occurs without any idea or a clue why. More over I tried to look for some lemmas and sentences regarding Quadratic residues without any clue.

Comment: I think if you write out the first few primes of each type the pattern will become clear.  Of course, then you have to prove that it holds generally.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether $p\equiv1\pmod4$. It is well known that
$$\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=\begin{cases}-1&\text{if }p\equiv1\pmod4,\\1&\text{if }p\equiv3\pmod4.\end{cases}$$
Note that
$$Q_2=\left\{(2k)^2\bmod p\mid0\le k\le\frac{p-1}2\right\}\bigcup\left\{-(2k+1)^2\bmod p\mid0\le k<\frac{p-1}2\right\},$$
denoted by $R_1\cup R_2$. Clearly $|R_1|=\frac{p+1}2$, for $(2i)^2\equiv(2j)^2\pmod p$ with $0\le i,j\le\frac{p-1}2$ only if $i=j$. Similarly we have $|R_2|=\frac{p-1}2$.

If $p\equiv1\pmod4$, then $-1\in R_1$, for $-1$ is a square modulo $p$. Thus $R_2\subset R_1$, and so $|Q_2|=\frac{p+1}2$.

If $p\equiv3\pmod4$, then $R_1\cap R_2$ is empty. The result then follows.